# Succesive write result in accessing the disk only once

Tags: c++, performance

In a given school excerice , i was requested to measure proccessor operation time.
Among other things, I was asked measure the time it takes to access the disk, and was strongly suggested to use functions on files.

Therefore, i came up with this simple "solution":

```
/* Time measurement function for accessing the disk.
   returns time in nano-seconds upon success,
   and -1 upon failure.
   */
double osm_disk_time(unsigned int iterations)
{
    // Check for illegal input
    iterations = (iterations == ILLEGAL_ITER_NUM) ? DEFAULT_ITER_NUM:iterations;

    // Start measuring.
    startTimeSuccess =  gettimeofday(&timeStart, NULL);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < iterations/ LOOP_FACTOR; ++i) {
        //operation. (loop unrolling): Write a char and flush memory

        if (fputs(LETTER_TO_WRITE, pFile) < SUCCESS || fflush(pFile) < SUCCESS)
        {
            return FAILURE;
        }

        if (fputs(LETTER_TO_WRITE, pFile) < SUCCESS || fflush(pFile) < SUCCESS)
        {
            return FAILURE;
        }

        if (fputs(LETTER_TO_WRITE, pFile) < SUCCESS || fflush(pFile) < SUCCESS)
        {
            return FAILURE;
        }
    }
    // Stop measuring.
    endTimeSuccess = gettimeofday(&timeEnd, NULL);

    return returnValueChecker(startTimeSuccess, endTimeSuccess, iterations);
}
```

The problem is that my measuring time was significantly below the avrege.
According to some research I did, I understand that multiple "writes" may access the disk only once, and this may be the reason why my measures arent accurate.
I dont understand why it happens and what can i do to fix this problem.

(PS: returnValueChecker() just check returning values).

Comment: I think because the OS/Program buffers your writes to be more efficient.

Comment: Use `flush()` after the `fputs()` statements.

Comment: Also can you use C++11? Because `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`, will probably be more precise.

Comment: Or even better, if you use Windows `QueryPerformanceFrequency`.

Comment: To measure, I'm bound to only use gettimeofday()

Comment: Micro-benchmarking is *hard*.  It's easy to measure the wrong thing.  [Chandler Carruth (clang developer) gave a talk at CppCon 2015 about using making microbenchmarks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXaxk27zwlk) that don't get optimized away, but also don't do extra work that you don't want to measure.  He spends a lot of time on Linux's `perf` tool for recording performance-counter info, but the concept applies to any tool.  There's also a nice framework for making microbenchmarks.  Watch the talk if you want to know how to isolate something and measure it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several levels of caching involved. The first one is in the library itself. You mitigate it using `fflush`. The second one is in the operating system, called page cache. And there is the third one - hardware cache in the disk drive itself.

To avoid caching effects there can be several strategies:

- Use files much larger then the amount of RAM available. This way the whole file cannot be cached in RAM.
- Use special calls to make a direct disk access (look it up in the OS documentation), or flush OS cache as well like you do with library cache. For example with POSIX's `fsync` call.
- You are most likely interested in the random access time. So create a big file (>RAM) and then read/write at random positions.

Comment: *read* at random positions after writing it out.  (A repeating pattern is fine; SSD compression shouldn't help too much with latency.)  Writes can be buffered, but `read` can't return until there's actually data.  To *really* prevent any overlap, make the next read position data-dependent on the previous read (i.e. pointer chasing, like how you test memory / CPU cache latency load-use delay.)

Comment: A stream of random writes will still be slow, but they can pipeline somewhat.  Hard drives get better throughput from higher queue depths.  `fsync` is a good suggestion, but will sync the metadata *and* the data.  `fdatasync` will only sync the data.  If you're trying to measure the latency of one disk seek, this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can call fsync(file_descriptor) after writing to the file.
The call will flush data in the buffer to the disk.
or
You can pass O_SYNC flag to open call for opening a file.
This will turn off the optimization i.e it will flush data to disk everytime you make a write call.